# Why Android Spinner onItemSelectedListener have two identical params

Tags: android, spinner, onitemselectedlistener

Can anyone please clarify why **onItemSelected()** method has both **position** and **id** params?

First I read the docs and didn't understand the difference. Then I tried watching both parameters in debug and they always have exactly same values. Also I wasn't able to find answer in google for that question, so my last resort is stackoverflow.

What's the difference between **position** and **id**?

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two parameters may have different values depending on how the underlying data is stored. For an `ArrayAdapter`, they are likely the same. However, for a `CursorAdapter`, the `position` is the position within the `Spinner` dropdown and the `id` is the primary key from the database table.